# The cohomology of the universal cover of a finite simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $L$ be a finite simplicial complex, and $K$ be its universal cover. Is there a easy way to see that $H^1(K,\mathbb{Z}_2)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal cover has trivial fundamental group, so since $H_1$ is the abelianization, $H_1(K)=0$.  Using the universal coefficient theorem, $H^1(K;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong\hom(H_1(K),\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=0$. (I am assuming $L$ is connected, but this all works component by component.)

Or think about it this way: $H^1(K;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ classifies real line bundles.  Concretely, if you take a loop $f:I\to K$ and follow it, keeping track of orientation of the fibers, the orientation at $f(1)$ might be the same as or be the reversal of the orientation at $f(0)$.  Letting $\alpha:\Omega K\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be such that $\alpha([f])=1$ if $f$ is an orientation-reversing loop and $\alpha([f])=0$ otherwise defines a $1$-cocycle; furthermore, $\alpha$ is only a function of the homotopy (actually homology) class of $f$.  Conversely, one can use a $1$-cocycle to determine how to glue together an $\mathbb{R}$-bundle over the simplicies.  If every loop in $K$ is homotopically trivial, then any particular $\mathbb{R}$-bundle is trivial, so $H^1(K;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=0$.